# call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects,got "string"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

local {

```
team   = "testing-env"
environment = "test-one"
aws_region = "us-east-1"
overrides_path = "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/overrides.yaml"
overrides = yamldecode(fileexists(local.overrides_path) ? file(local.overrides_path) : "{}")
overridden = fileexists(local.overrides_path) ? merge(local.overrides.base_s3) : {}
```

}

Overrides.yaml

```
base_s3:
  team = "staging-one"
  aws_region = "us-east-1"
```

when I run Terragrunt fmt this is the error I'm receiving:

Error: Error in function call

/stage/terragrunt.hcl line 7, in locals:
7:     overridden = fileexists(local.overrides_path) ? merge(local.overrides.base_s3) : {}

with local.overrides.base_s3 as "team = "staging-one"" aws_region = "us-east-1"".

Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got "string".

please how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Overrides.yaml` just defines a string in yaml, not any object, thus there is nothing to merge. Maybe you want:

```
base_s3:
  team: "staging-one"
  aws_region: "us-east-1"
```

Comment: so what do i need to change in my overrides.yaml to make it work please?

Comment: @dcloud You need to change your yaml file as I wrote in the answer

Comment: I added this but still wont accept it   base_s3:
  team: "staging-one"
  aws_region: "us-east-1"

Comment: can you please help suggest how to write the yaml file to enable merge

Comment: @dcloud You are not merging anything in your `merge(local.overrides.base_s3)`. You don't need merge at all here. You have only single map of `local.overrides.base_s3`.

Comment: thank you so much..it worked.you are the best

Comment: can you please take a look at this for me please?I just posted another question ,wanted to send to you here but saying too long.